# Remove _embedded in HATEOAS link using spring-boot-2.2.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-hateoas

I am using spring-boot-2.2.1 along with spring-HATEOAS. Hypermedia links are working fine but 
I see `_embedded` attribute while returning links, Please find the below code for reference and the project in github [here](https://github.com/VelDeveloper/spring-boot-unittest),

**Endpoint :**

a) Will return `CollectionModel` => localhost:8099/api/v1/capability/list/noembedded

and

b) Will return List< EntityModel< Capability>> localhost:8099/api/v1/capability/list/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-unittest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-unittest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot unit test</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Embedded  MongoDB for Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <!--<processor>com.querydsl.mongodb.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor</processor>-->
                            <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Controller.Java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/capability")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin
public class CapabilityController {

    private final CapabilityService capabilityService;
    private final CapabilityResourceAssembler capabilityResourceAssembler;

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public CollectionModel<EntityModel<Capability>> getAllCapabilities() {
       List<EntityModel<Capability>> capabilities = capabilityService.listCapabilities().stream()
               .map(capability -> new EntityModel<>(capability,
                       linkTo(methodOn(CapabilityController.class).getCapabilityById(capability.getId())).withRel("getThisCapability"),
                       linkTo(methodOn(CapabilityController.class).getAllCapabilities()).withRel("getAllCapabilities")
               )).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new CollectionModel<>(capabilities);
    }
}
```

Actual response

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "capabilityList": [
      {
        "id": "sample",
        "techStack": "Java",
        "numOfDevelopers": 25,
        "numOfAvailableDevelopers": 10,
        "_links": {
          "getThisCapability": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8099/api/v1/capability/sample"
          },
          "getAllCapabilities": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8099/api/v1/capability/list"
          },
          "deleteThisCapability": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8099/api/v1/capability/sample"
          },
          "createCapability": {
            "href": "localhost:8099/api/v1/capability"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Response :

```
[
  {
    "id": "sample",
    "techStack": "Java",
    "numOfDevelopers": 25,
    "numOfAvailableDevelopers": 10,
    "_links": {
      "getThisCapability": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8099/api/v1/capability/sample"
      },
      "getAllCapabilities": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8099/api/v1/capability/list"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried

> spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType = application/json
>
> spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false

But no luck still I am able to see `_embedded` attribute in the response.
Could anyone please help me to identify the issue.

I was using `spring-boot-1.5.10` before there I am able to render links properly without `_embedded`, Please refer [here](https://github.com/VelDeveloper/spring-hypermedia).

It is working fine after I added below annotation in the main class and if I return List

> @EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)

localhost:9771/api/v1/capability/list

This produces below result :

```
[
  {
    "capabilityId": "sample",
    "techStack": "Java",
    "numOfDevelopers": 25,
    "numOfAvailableDevelopers": 10,
    "_links": {
      "getThisCapability": {
        "href": "http://localhost:9771/api/v1/capability/sample"
      },
      "getAllCapabilities": {
        "href": "http://localhost:9771/api/v1/capability/list"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Unfortunately, It is not working in the latest version.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The example code doesn't seem to reproduce the behaviour in your question. Running `SpringBootUnittestApplication` and accessing `:8099/api/v1/capability/list` returns an empty JSON object. I guess because the data store is empty? Can you update the examples to make them as minimal as possible, for example by removing the dependency on Mongo and hardcoding some data?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks a lot for your reply. Sure, let me update the Github.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Pushed changes in both the github repository by disabling MongoDB. Please check this endpoint localhost:<portNumber>/api/v1/capability/list/noembedded for both the project. In spring-boot-unittest repo links will not be rendered properly which is using spring-boot-2.x and in spring-hypermedia links are rendered properly which is using spring-boot.15.x. your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Spring Boot 1.5, you were relying on a limitation of Spring HATEOAS that resulted in the Jackson `ObjectMapper` that is intended to be HAL-specific being used as the application-wide `ObjectMapper`. This pollution meant that HAL formatting was applied to responses when it should not have been.

The limitation has been addressed in Spring HATEOAS 1.0 and its HAL-specific `ObjectMapper` no longer pollutes the whole application. If you want the main application `ObjectMapper` to apply HAL-style serialisation you can opt back in by customising it:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder,
                                 HypermediaMappingInformation mappingInformation) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
    mappingInformation.configureObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

While I think the above will work, I will echo the concern that [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7487521/daniel) raised in their answer about the response format and compliance with the HAL spec.

Comment: It is working fine perfectly!!! Thanks a lot for your messages.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the [HAL specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) correctly that would be invalid HAL, which is why Spring HATEOAS will not produce this result as long as you return a `CollectionModel` in your request. Mind that it is possible for the collection to have links as well, which would be next to the `_embedded` property in a `_links` property as depicted in [this example document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08#section-6).

In case you really want to get rid of the `_embedded` property and produce a list of `EntityModel<T>`s, then it should work if you modify your code to return a `List<EntityModel<Capability>>`. You will then lose the `_embedded` and `_links` properties that are produced by Spring HATEOAS. Here is your modified code snippet:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/capability")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin
public class CapabilityController {

    private final CapabilityService capabilityService;
    private final CapabilityResourceAssembler capabilityResourceAssembler;

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public List<EntityModel<Capability>> getAllCapabilities() {
       List<EntityModel<Capability>> capabilities = capabilityService.listCapabilities().stream()
               .map(capability -> new EntityModel<>(capability,
                       linkTo(methodOn(CapabilityController.class).getCapabilityById(capability.getId())).withRel("getThisCapability"),
                       linkTo(methodOn(CapabilityController.class).getAllCapabilities()).withRel("getAllCapabilities")
               )).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return capabilities;
    }
}
```

I'd strongly advise against this as you lose the advantages of Spring HATEOAS.

Additionally I recommend to make use of your `CapabilityResourceAssembler` and create the `EntityModel<Capability>` instances through the use of `capabilityResourceAssembler.toModel(...)` so you don't have to repeat the code you implemented in your `.map(...)` function.

Comment: I know this solution. I am already using it for one of my APIs. But if we use EntityModel for List then we are losing _links as well as you mentioned. I would like to maintain _links.

Comment: Currently that does not seem to be possible in Spring HATEOAS. It would also clash with any class that you return (may it not be `List`) which has a `_links` property.

Comment: Could you please check my question again. I have updated it. It was working fine with older version.

Comment: @VelNaga Looking at your updated question and the code you provided, I immediately noticed that you are returning `List<Capability>` ( https://github.com/VelDeveloper/spring-hypermedia/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hypermedia/demo/controller/CapabilityController.java#L27 ), not `Resources<Capability>` which would be the proper way to return a collection of resources. Therefore, in the old project, you have done the same as I have proposed above - you should not have been able to see any links that are collection related in the code you provided through GitHub. Can you please check that?

Comment: `Capability` extends `RecourseSupport` so List<Capability> means the list of resources since I don't want `_embedded` in the response. If I return `Resources<Capability>` then my response would contain `_embedded`. Main thing to note in the old API is, I am able to see `_links` in the response and the links in response are rendered properly which is not working in new API.

Comment: When you moved over to the new API you have changed the return type of your method from a _collection of resources_ to a _resource_ that contains multiple resources (`CollectionModel`). To achieve the exact same as before, return `List<EntityModel<Capability>>`. In the old API you should not have seen any links beside the array. In the new API you can, because it is a resource (`CollectionModel`). Look exactly where the `_links` property you mention sits in the hierarchy, it belongs to a single `Capability` object - not the collection. And returning `EntityModel`s will keep this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206733/discussion-between-daniel-and-velnaga).

Comment: Pushed changes in both the github repository by disabling MongoDB. Please check this endpoint localhost:<portNumber>/api/v1/capability/list/noembedded for both the project. In spring-boot-unittest repo links will not be rendered properly which is using spring-boot-2.x and in spring-hypermedia links are rendered properly which is using spring-boot.15.x. your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: So I checked your code again. It's basically the same, except for the `EntityModel` which is not correctly serialized in 2.2.1. I suggest you find out how to serialize instances of `EntityModel` contained in a `List` and then use my proposed solution detailed in my answer. But I still encourage you to use the `CollectionModel` and use HAL correctly so you will have links on the collection level.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to extend CollectionModel with a filed of type collection annotated @JsonValue, then in your assembler override toCollectionModel to return the custom CollectionModel

```
public class CustomCollectionModel<T> extends CollectionModel<CollectionModel<T>>  {
@JsonValue
private Collection<T> content;

protected CustomCollectionModel() {
    this(new ArrayList<>());
}

public CustomCollectionModel(Iterable<T> content, Link... links) {
    this(content, Arrays.asList(links));
}


public CustomCollectionModel(Iterable<T> content, Iterable<Link> links) {

    Assert.notNull(content, "Content must not be null!");

    this.content = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T element : content) {
        this.content.add(element);
    }

    this.add(links);
}}
```

and then in your assembler

```
  @Override
public CustomCollectionModel toCollectionModel(Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
    List<EntityModel<T>> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T entity : entities) {
        resourceList.add(toModel(entity));
    }
    return new CustomCollectionModel(resourceList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this still an issue for you?
I was able to remove the _embedded attribute by passing false as an argument to useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType method in RepositoryRestConfiguration class.

Answer (score 0):

I found this soluction.

```
@Component
public class ResourceProcessorEmpty implements RepresentationModelProcessor<CollectionModel<Object>> {


    @Override
    public CollectionModel<Object> process(CollectionModel<Object> resourceToThrowAway) {
        if (resourceToThrowAway.getContent().size() != 1) {
            return resourceToThrowAway;
        }
        if (!resourceToThrowAway.getContent().iterator().next().getClass().getCanonicalName().contains("EmptyCollectionEmbeddedWrapper")) {
            return resourceToThrowAway;
        }

        CollectionModel<Object> newResource = CollectionModel.empty();
        newResource.add(resourceToThrowAway.getLinks());
        return newResource;
    }
}
```